# .NET MVC One-to-One relationship

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an Expression of Interest Form which uses the following model

```
public class dsExpressionOfInterest
{
    public int dsExpressionOfInterestID { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter a Date")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date")]
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Contact Person")]
    [Display(Name = "Contact Person")]
    public string ContactPerson { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the Telephone Number")]
    [Display(Name = "Telephone")]
    public string Telephone { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter the nature of the query")]
    [Display(Name = "Nature of query")]
    public string NatureOfQuery { get; set; }

    public virtual dsRegistration dsRegistration { get; set; }
}
```

I also have  Registration Form which has the following model

```
public class dsRegistration
{
    public int dsRegistrationID { get; set; }

    public int dsExpressionOfInterestID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SLA")]
    public bool SLAReceived { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Received")]
    public DateTime? SLAReceivedDate { get; set; }

    public virtual dsExpressionOfInterest dsExpressionOfInterest { get; set; }
}
```

My problem is I am unsure of how to set the relationship between these two models.
You must have a record in the Expression Of Interest Table before a Registration Record can be created.

At the minute I am getting the error

```
Unable to determine the principal end of an association between the types
```

In effect its a One-to-One relationship on dsExpressionOfInterestID

Do I need to use data annotations, and if so can someone point me in the right direction please?

Comment: Have a look at C# naming conventions online. Your naming scheme is unusual for C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is that it's not clear what's the parent and what's the child table. Have you tried removing the link to the parent in the child class?

```
public class dsRegistration
{
    public int dsRegistrationID { get; set; }

    public int dsExpressionOfInterestID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "SLA")]
    public bool SLAReceived { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Date Received")]
    public DateTime? SLAReceivedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Getting the error The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint

Comment: Are you adding these tables for the first time or updating existing tables? Are you doing something similar to this: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650257/adding-a-foreign-key-with-code-first-migration)?

Comment: Got it working. I needed to Force the Migration to re-scaffold it.