# How to migrate to production adding a new relation in the database using code first approach

Tags: sql-server, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations

I need an advice for a release to production strategy using entity framework core given this scenario.
I have an existing database generated using code first approach. On that database I have an Entity A. The corresponding Diagram of this table is

[image]

Then I have created a new table B and its corresponding diagram is:

[image]

I want to create a relation one to many between A and B as follows: an entity of A is related with one of B, and an entity of B could have many A’s. In the entity A I added a new foreign key column named IdB to represent the relation. This column value is required so it couldn’t be null.

[image]

When I create this relation I got this error message:
'The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint'
Following the instruction in this link:

[Adding a new relation to existing database using entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49057874/adding-a-new-relation-to-existing-database-using-entity-framework)

I used to test both approaches:

1. Remove the constrain IsRequired on the entity A for the foreign key, making this field nullable. Performing a migration. Then Seeding the data. Finally perform another migration to add the IsRequired constrain for the foreign key.
2. Add a migration and modify the generated class method Up() to make the column nullable and at the end add the foreign key and the required constrain.

When moving to production:

For the first approach I’m requiring two releases, one for each migration.
For the second approach, is required to know the section of the Up Method to edit and at this point when join with other pending migration files make difficult to follow up and modified a code that it is suppose to be ready to enter to production.

My question goes to an advice for an approach to release to production with only one release and then a Seed data process. We could perform several migrations, but they should executed in only one release.
Thank you
Francisco

Comment: So is your question about adding a relation or deploying multiple migrations to production? For your relations, show the models since you tagged this Code First (don't change the database directly). For migrating, what is your strategy for updating production (running migrations directly or script generation) ?

Comment: Hi, my question is related to an strategy to moving for production. On Development environment I was able to create the database using several migration and Seeding. Related if a code first question yes it is. I just shown the created models generated by SSMS. For production we run migrations directly. Thank you, Francisco