# Adding foreign key on database with existing records on Prodution. Migration approaches using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, production-environment

There are often scenarios where for example when you add a new foreign key to a table or drop a foreign key, you can some foreign key constraints errors. To fix this, we need to remove all records from the database and the migration works fine.

This approach is perfect on development environment but we cannot do this on Production.

Are there any guidelines on entity framework or approaches to handle entity framework on production?

Comment: i see only one way that you need to fix broken ids. For example creating records in source table with this identifier or remove invalid records in target table.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Migration feature is created to keep database sync with application regardless of the environment where application runs. Since It's obvious that the migration scripts should be created in an organized and functional manner to avoid conflicts or data-loss, you may need to **manually revise auto-generated conflicting migration scripts** sometimes (Take a look at Up() Method of recently added migration class and look for suspicious `MigrationBuilder` commands).

However, it's most likely you are facing errors that are getting raised by database itself. Note that:

- If a FK column is going to get dropped, **dependency error** will be raised and that means the constraint must be dropped sooner.
- If a FK column is going to get added, since the new field doesn't have a valid value and it's possibly set to non-null property, database will fail to make constraint between existing records and destination table. In this case, it's required to create the field as nullable. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650257/adding-a-foreign-key-with-code-first-migration/43739826).

**TLDR;**

You don't need to delete existing database, just find possible conflicts in model schema or migration scripts and resolve them.