# How to add a foreign key when the primary table contains data but the dependent table does not

Tags: .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm working with an EF Core 5, code first database and my migration is trying to add a foreign key between an existing table that already contains data and a new table that will not contain data until after the migration has finished. My problem is that the foreign key cannot be added because the constraint is immediately invalid because I have not yet populated the new table with the appropriate data that will satisfy the constraint.

I can work around it my first adding the new table, populating it and then adding a new migration that adds the foreign key, but that seems like a hack that will not work under certain conditions.

BTW, my database is Postgresql

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650257/adding-a-foreign-key-with-code-first-migration ?
There is an example of how to do it using more than one migration, and an example of how to edit your migration to only do one migration.

Answer (score 0):

there's solution to create the 2 new tables with the constraints and move the data to the new tables